# windows 7 ${product_name}

Tags: windows, windows-7

I have this ***${PRODUCT_NAME}*** item in my start menu, and it has only one malfunctioning "Help" file in it which was for a program which I have since removed/uninstalled. I'm quite sure it was also there even before I installed that removed program.

I'm using Windows-7, is it a OS thingy? Is it safe to just delete it the right click way or any proper disposal method?

Comment: It's not an OS thingy. Sounds like somebody made a mistake when creating the installer package. It's safe to remove.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it `*${product_name}*` or `${product_name}` (without the asterisks)? Because asterisks are illegal in standard Win32 paths.

Comment: @Bob I think you are right I was also thinking about it and thought to edit it but suddenly I thought it would be better to ask about this. +1 for good point. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting you right then you can create a backup or restore point and then you can delete this file without hesitation. As in any case you get any problem you can repair your PC or you can restore it on the restore point you have created.

As I know some programs don't uninstall all contents of when they uninstall through the control panel. As `winamp` is one of them when you will uninstall it then it gives a message at the end that *all files were not deleted* so then you have to delete them manually. So AFAIK there should be no problem to delete this file.